# array in php and dict in python are the same?

Tags: php, python, arrays

I have a project using python and i want to convert the php to python. I have confused in the array of php in converting it to python...

in the old code of the php... it looks like this,

```
array(
      "Code"          => 122,
      "Reference"     => 1311,
      "Type"          => 'NT',
      "Amount"        => 100.00
);
```

and this is what i did in converting it to python ...

```
dict = {
          "Code":122,
          "Reference":1311,
          "Type":'NT',
          "Amount":100.00
}
```

is my converting php to python is correct?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your conversion is essentially correct (though I wouldn't use *dict* as a variable name since that masks a built-in class constructor of the same name).  That being said, [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) are *ordered mappings*, so you should use a [Python OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead of a regular dict so that the order of insertion gets preserved:

```
>>> import collections
>>> od = collections.OrderedDict([
        ('Code', 122),
        ('Reference', 1311),
        ('Type', 'NT'),
        ('Amount', 100.00),
])

>>> print od['Amount']
100.0

>>> od.keys()
['Code', 'Reference', 'Type', 'Amount']
```

Answer (score 0):

To be specific, a PHP *associative* array is the same as a Python dictionary, and the PHP associative array is *ordered*. Ruby hash tables are same as PHP associative arrays (ordered key-value pairs).

Python lists and PHP arrays are the same (unordered lists of non-keyed values). Ruby arrays are the same as Python and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

PHP arrays are different from py objects that:

- PHP keys can be integers or strings (associative),
- When a value is appended to an array, a numeric key is automatically
  assigned before appending the key/value pair to the array.
  The assigned associated key has integer value that equals to the maximum
  of the array's internal numeric iterator index keys plus 1,
- Numeric integer keys in string are casted into integers,
- The order of insertion to the array is preserved. key/value pairs are
  iterated according to the insertion order of the keys. We can use Python's
  OrderedDict to emulate,
- PHP `array[] = 5` is translated to Python `array.append(5)` or
  `array[None] = 5`,
- The iterator index keys are manipulated through PHP built-in functions, or
  are passed by reference, with a copy on write policy.

I'd like to give a plug to my newly released product `pyx.php` Python module.
There is a Python class `array` in the module that emulates a PHP array.
Our Python emulation of the PHP array uses an OrderedDict instance variable,
where array._obj is an OrderedDic to store all elements of the array and
keep track of their orders of insertion using a custom pointer instance
variable.  Try:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/wordpy/pyx/
$ python # or ipython`

>>> import pyx.php as Php; array = Php.array
>>> arr1 = array( (0,'1-0'),('a','1-a'),('b','1-b'),)
>>> arr2 = array( (0,'2-0'),(  1,'2-1'),('b','2-b'),('c','2-c'),)
>>> arr1 + arr2   # same as: Php.array_plus(arr1, arr2), see below
>>> Php.array_merge(arr1, arr2)

>>> import pyx.php as Php;  array = Php.array
>>> Arr0 = array()   # Arr0._obj is an empty OrderedDict()
>>> Arr1 = array( ('a',11), 'zzz', (99,99), 22, 33, (2,22) )
>>> Arr1
array(6) {
  ['a']=> <int> 11
  [0]=> <str> zzz
  [99]=> <int> 99
  [100]=> <int> 22
  [101]=> <int> 33
  [2]=> <int> 22
}
```

`zip()` works for array with different len !!!

```
>>> for i,j in zip( array(1,2,3,4), array(11,22,33) ):
...   print(i,j)
1 11
2 22
3 33
>>> for i,j in zip( array(1,2), array(11,22,33) ):
...   print(i,j)
1 11
2 22
```

`array()` in the `pyx.php` Cython module offers almost everything that
a PHP array() offers, plus many more methods.
Please see https://wordpy.com/pyx/php/.

Currently, `pyx.php` is only available for Python 3.x running 64-bit Linux.
Python 2.x, Mac, or other platforms can be compiled when there are many
requests.